# How to get the default DISPLAY variable?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, display

When creating a new shell session, the `DISPLAY` variable is set accordingly (it can be `:0`, `:1`, `localhost:0`, etc.).  If I accidentally messed up the `DISPLAY` variable, usually I want it reset to this default value (which changes depending on setup).

My question is, how can I programmatically (via bash script) get the `DISPLAY` variable **as it would have been when creating a new shell**?

Other questions / answers usually involving just hard coding `export DISPLAY=0:0` or something similar which isn't what I want (since the correct `DISPLAY` variable may be different)

My naive attempts

```
bash -c 'echo $DISPLAY'
```

don't work because subshells inherit the current shell variables

Answer (score 2):

You can examine `/proc/${pid}/environ`.  That contains the process' initial environment.

Here, `$$` is the pid of the running shell.  Note also that the variables are nil-character delimited.  The `-e` option to `cat` will cause it to print non-printable characters (like the nil character), and the `sed` converts the representation of the nil characters to newlines.

```
$ cat -e "/proc/$$/environ" | sed 's/\^@/\n/g' | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0.0

$ export DISPLAY=broken

$ cat -e "/proc/$$/environ" | sed 's/\^@/\n/g' | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Comment: Somehow I managed to mess up the environment enough that `environ` was giving the incorrect display...  prolly something to do with `tmux-resurrect` and friends...

Comment: @Rufus if you started a new shell after mucking with `DISPLAY` the new shell would have the modified value (but the parent would have the original).

Comment: It should not be updated: *"This file contains the initial environment that was set
 when the currently executing program was **started** via execve(2)."* [man proc.5](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) - Further *" If, after an execve(2), the process modifies its environment (e.g., by calling functions such as putenv(3) or modifying the environ(7) variable directly), **this file will not reflect those changes**."*

Answer (score 0):

One way I can get the correct `DISPLAY` is by querying the `DISPLAY` variable assigned to `gnome-terminal-server` with the following

```
cat /proc/$(pidof "gnome-terminal-server")/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | grep ^DISPLAY=
```